# Which keymap entries determine add/ subtract/ new selection when window/lasso selection?

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools

I am looking for the commands that are responsible for determining window (and lasso) selection behavior when selecting vertices, because I want to set them up closer to 3ds Max' selection keys.
In my keymap however, ctrl subtracts from the selection, rather than adding, Shift adds to the selection, but I would like for it to toggle select. Alt does not even do anything at the moment, but it should be used to deselect. This behaviour is shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9PPq.jpg

Comment: If you haven't already tried, in the edit preferences menu, under keymap, you can choose Industry Compatible as your keymap so it feels a bit more like 3ds max.

Comment: I have completely customised my hotkeys already, this is just the final touch that needs to be done. I can't seem to find the commands that I am looking for.